# Doctrine oneToOne doesn't work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Card Entity with a oneToOne relation to User Entity

```
MyBundle\Entity\Card:
    type: entity
    table: mm_card
    repositoryClass: CardRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        code:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 16
    manyToOne:
        company:
            targetEntity: User
            inversedBy: companyCards
            joinColumn:
                name: company_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: false
                onDelete: cascade
        createdBy:
            targetEntity: User
            joinColumn:
                name: created_by
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: true
            gedmo:
                blameable:
                    on: create
        updatedBy:
            targetEntity: User
            joinColumn:
                name: updated_by
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: true
            gedmo:
                blameable:
                    on: update
    oneToOne:
        owner:
            targetEntity: User
            joinColumn:
                name: owner_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: true
                onDelete: SET NULL
```

When I use stanard CRUD with a Form to edit the Card Class, and I have there EntityType:class with User when I choose a User and save it works. But if in API I want to do the same, id doesn't:

```
$cardObj = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Card')->find(16);
$userObj = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:User')->find(10);
$cardObj->setOwner($userObj);
$em->flush();
```

I get error in DB:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, maccount_type, mcompany_type, mphoto, mphoto_guid, mcompany_code, billing_first_name, billing_last_name, billing_company, billing_phone, billing_country, billing_street, billing_building_nb, billing_local_nb, billing_city, billing_state, billing_postcode, mdescription, wp_user_id, master_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)':\n\nSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with you .yaml configuration.

Look at examples in official [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional).
For example:

```
 Product:
  type: entity
  oneToOne:
    shipping:
      targetEntity: Shipping
      joinColumn:
        name: shipping_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I have the same configuration except additionally added nullable and onDelete

Comment: You start configuration from Mapping (oneToOne) then enter Entity name (owner), it's it is wrong.
First you mast give name Entity, and then create mapping to another Entity.

Comment: This code is just exerpt from the whole Entity definition. And it is ok. It should work cause using a form I can set OneToOne relation properly. But this is really weird

Comment: Unfortunately i don't see all code, and i can't told you in 100% right  variant what you need to do.

Comment: Of course, if this help, I have updated the code. Please check it.

Comment: You set $userObj in Entity - Owner, then you get error: "INSERT INTO user". It's strange, must be something like this: "INSERT INTO owner". Maybe you get user with not valid data's?

Comment: User and Card already exists, see the next code. There should be no INSERT. Only UPDATE card SET owner = 10 WHERE Id = 16